# Inverse of Upper Triangular matrix algorithm

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the code to compute inverse of lower triangular matrix. How to compute inverse of upper triangular matrix from below code by changing it a little bit?

```
function L = L_inv(A)
            [n,n] = size(A);
            L = zeros(n); 
            for i=1:n
                L(i,i) = 1/A(i,i);
                for j=i+1:n
                    L(j,i)=-A(j, i:j-1)*L(i:j-1,i)/A(j,j);
                end
            end
        end
```

Comment: My linear algebra is quite rusty, but if I remember correctly an upper triangular matrix is just a transpose of a lower one, and the inverse of the transpose of a matrix is equal to the transpose of the inverse. If that's true, just apply your function to the transpose of your upper triangular matrix and then transpose back the result.

Comment: @MatteoV Are you sure , I also thought of same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of the transpose of a matrix is equal to the transpose of its inverse.
So, since an upper triangular matrix is just the transpose of a lower triangular matrix, to find the inverse of an upper triangular matrix you just need to apply your function to its transpose and then transpose again the result.

```
n = 10; % dimensions of your matrix
U = triu(rand(n, n)); % create a random upper triangular matrix
Uinv1 = L_inv(U')'; % using your function
Uinv2 = inv(U); % using the built-in function
Uinv1 - Uinv2
```

Printing the difference between the two results you can see that they are (almost) exactly the same. For example in my case `norm(Uinv1 - Uinv2) = 5.642266075279820e-15`.